# Websocket errors post AKS Upgrade from 1.23 to 1.25/1.26

Tags: vue.js, kubernetes, webpack, azure-aks

We have a Vue.js application deployed on AKS which works fine on AKS Version 1.23 although producing some webpack/websocket errors in the console.

However, when we upgrade our AKS Cluster to 1.25 or 1.26, although the pods are up, there is no issue in the build/deployment, we are not able to get the page up.

Error 1 in console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://DOMAIN_NAME/' was
> loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket
> endpoint 'ws://**POD_IP**:8081/ws'. This request has been blocked;
> this endpoint must be available over WSS.

This is strange as in 1.23 we get `ws://**DOMAIN_NAME**:8081/ws` while in 1.25/26 it redirects us to the internal Pod IP.

Error 2 in console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
    at new WebSocketClient (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/clients/WebSocketClient.js:21:19)
    at initSocket (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js:31:12)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=10.101.14.228&port=8081&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true:321:55)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws&hostname=10.101.14.228&port=8081&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true
```

When we deploy the same application with same settings on AKS 1.24, it works fine.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but reading the Kubernetes 1.26 release notes, maybe this could be the reason? [Remove kube-proxy userspace modes #112133](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/112133)

Was thinking this might be related since your talking about redirecting and maybe that is handled by the kubeproxy instead of using an ingress?

What does the yaml look like?

Comment: Viktoria, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)